# Error message when trying to install IHRIS sofware

Tags: networking, apt, upgrade, updates, update-manager

i am trying to install a medical software called "IHRIS" but when running the command in ubuntu i am getting the following error message. How do i go about it. Kindly assist. Thank you.

Error message.
Err:6 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy Release
404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.40 80]
Err:7 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/openhie/release/ubuntu jammy Release
404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
Err:8 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates Release
404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.40 80]
Err:9 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports Release
404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.40 80]
Err:10 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security Release
404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.40 80]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** To help in better troubleshooting your issue, please edit your question to include the version of the Ubuntu OS that you're running. Thanks